Prove the function $g(x,y,t)\ge1$
I have the function
$$
g(x,y,t)=\frac{(8x^2y^2+f_+(x,y,t)-\cos(2t))(8x^2y^2(1+(x+y)^2)+(x+y)^2(f_-(x,y,t)-\cos(t))+4xy(x+y)\sin(2t))}{64x^4y^4(1+(x+y)^2)}
$$
with
$$
f_{\pm}(x,y,t) = 1+2x^2+2y^2\pm4xy\cos(2t)-2(x+y)\sin(2t).
$$
Is is possible to analytically prove $g(x,y,t)\ge1$? I have numerically checked it for many values of variables (x,y,t). Any suggestion will be helpful.
Just in case, the MMA code of this function is
fp[x_, y_, t_] = 
  1 + 2 x^2 + 2 y^2 + 4 x y Cos[2 t] - 2(x + y)Sin[2t];
fm[x_, y_, t_] = 
  1 + 2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - 4 x y Cos[2 t] - 2(x + y)Sin[2t];
g[x_, y_, 
   t_] = (8 x^2 y^2 + fp[x, y, t] - 
     Cos[2 t]) (8 x^2 y^2 (1 + (x + y)^2) + (x + y)^2 (fm[x, y, t] - 
         Cos[2t]) + 
      4 (x + y) x y Sin[2 t])/(64 x^4 y^4 (1 + (x + y)^2));


This inequality is not true. E.g.,
$$g\Big(\frac1{10},\frac1{10},\frac\pi4\Big)=-1783.256\ldots\not\ge1.$$

The OP has changed the problem, thus invalidating the previous answer. After the change, the answer becomes positive. Indeed, the problem is a real algebraic one, since, for any real $u$ and $v$, one can find a real $t$ such that $u=\cos2t$ and $v=\sin2t$ iff $u^2+v^2=1$. Any real algebraic problem can be solved purely algorithmically. In Mathematica, such algorithms are realized via commands Reduce, FindInstance, etc.
In particular, for the function $g$ defined by the Mathematica code in the OP, Mathematica confirms (in about 2.8 sec) that the set of all real triples $(x,y,t)$ such that $g(x,y,t)<1$ is empty:


I used ChatGPT to check your calculation. It took me no more than 1 minute. Stupid, but useful tool.

@PiotrHajlasz : ChatGPT can certainly be a useful tool. See e.g. this.

@IosifPinelis Why is your link telling me about the world's thinnest portable? Portable what?! I already have very thin portable paper to write on with a staggeringly lightweight pencil.

Sorry for this. It is a typo in the inequality and I have edited my question. Just in case, I gave the MMA code of the function $g(x,y,t)$.

@DaveBenson : The link was https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/1emzfax/mathematician_terence_tao_says_ai_is_already/ I don't know why you were getting something else.

@Guoqing : In such cases, you should take the complete responsibility for whatever mistakes in your post (which in this case do not look to me like a simple typo). Then you can post the amended question separately.

@IosifPinelis The link took me to something called Reddit, which pushed an advertisement on me. This in spite of having AdBlock Plus installed. It's an internet disease that I deplore.

@DaveBenson : Here is a better link, where Tao discusses "challeng[es of] incorporat[ing] assistance from modern AI tools into a research project". See also this, concerning "how best to use the AI tools of the future".

Thanks @IosifPinelis. The Terry Tao link is great. This Reddit seemingly sucks. I still don't know what it is, and I'm not sure I want to know.

@Guoqing : Do you have a further response to my answer?
